# Applied statistics in Machine Learning, AI, Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, statistics

I hope this is the right forum bcoz I couldn't find one which seems exactly relevant. Question is, are any of the following topics from Statistics really useful from point of view of being applicable while working with Machine Learning, AI and Neural Networks?

A)Descriptive Statistics

```
Analysis of Quantitative Data:
- Measures of central tendancy
- Measures of dispersion
- Moments
- Skewness and Kurtosis
Correlation of bivariate data:
- Fitting of curves
- Correlation coefficient
- Rank Correlation
- Intra-class Corelation
Regression and Multiple Correlations
- Linear Regression
- Plane of Regression
- Multiple Correlation
- Partial Correlation
Theory of Attributes
- Classification of Attributes
- Independence of Attributes
- Association of Attributes
```

B)Probability Theory

```
Basic Concepts in Probability
- Introduction to Probability
- Different Approaches to Probability Theory
- Laws of Probability
- Bayes' Theorem
Random Variables and Expectation
- Random Variables
- Bivariate Discrete Random Variables
- Bivariate Continuous Random Variables
- Mathematical Expectation
Discrete Probability Distributions
- Binomial Distributions
- Poisson Distributions
- Discrete Uniform and Hypergeometric Distributions
- Geometric and Negative Binomial Distributions
Continuous Probability Distributions
- Normal Distributions
- Area Property of Normal Distributions
- Continuous Uniform and Exponential Distributions
- Gamma and Beta Distributions
```

C)Statistical Inference

```
 Sampling Distributions
 - Introduction to Sampling Distributions
 - Sampling Distributions of Statistics
 - Standard Sampling Distributions
 Estimation
 - Introduction to Estimation
 - Point Estimation
 - Interval Estimation for One Population
 - Interval Estimation for Two Populations
 Testing of Hypothesis
 - Concepts of Testing of Hypothesis
 - Large Sample Tests
 - Small Sample Tests
 - Chi-Square and F-Tests
 Non-Parametric Tests
 - One-Sample Tests
 - Two-Sample Tests
 - k-Sample Tests
 - Analysis of Frequencies
```

D)Statistical Techniques

```
Sampling Designs
- Introduction to Sample Surveys
- Simple Random Sampling
- Stratified Random Sampling
- Other Sampling Schemes
Analysis of Variance
- Introduction
- One-way Analysis of Variance
- Two-way Analysis of Variance
- Two-way Analysis of Variance with m Observations per call
Design of Experiments
- Completely Randomized Design
- Randomized block Design
- Latin Square Design
- Factorial Experiments
Random Numbers Generation and Simulation Techniques
- Random Numbers Generation for Discrete Variables
- Random Numbers Generation for Continuous Variables
- Simulation Techniques
- Applications of Simulation
```

E)Industrial Statistics - I

```
Process Control
- Introduction to Statistical Quality Control
- Control Charts for Variables
- Control Charts for Attributes
- Control Charts for Defects
Product Control
- Acceptance Sampling Plans
- Rectifying Sampling Plans
- Single Sampling Plans
- Double Sampling Plans
Decision and Game Theory
- Introduction to Decision Theory
- Decision making Process
- Two-Person Zero-Sum Games with Saddle Point
- Two-Person Zero-Sum Games without Saddle Point
Reliability Theory
- Introduction to Reliability
- Reliability Evaluation of Simple System
- Reliability Evaluation of k-out-of-n and StandBy System
- Reliability Evaluation of Complex System
```

F)Industrial Statistics - II

```
Optimisation Techniques I 
- Introduction to Operations Research
- Linear Programming Problems
- Simplex Method
- Transportation Problems
Optimisation Techniques II
- Assignment Problems
- Queueing Theory
- Sequencing Problems
- Inventory Models
Regression Modelling
- Simple Linear Regression
- Statistical Inference in Simple Linear Regression
- Multiple Linear Regression
- Selection of Variables and Testing Model Assumptions
Time Series Modelling
- Trend Component Analysis
- Seasonal Component Analysis
- Stationary Processes
- Time Series Models
```

EDIT: In reply to @SmallChess; honestly, both these areas are new to me but I find them really interesting. Ultimately I wish to work in Physics and be able to apply it there. Example, following links:

[link1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239166/is-machine-learning-a-useful-tool-for-analyzing-experimental-data)  [link2](https://www.quora.com/How-is-machine-learning-used-in-physics)  [link3](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relationship-between-physics-and-machine-learning-AI)

Perhaps this is still quite broad. But I haven't really put my finger on anything specific as yet. Best way I can narrow it down is probably through above links and following excerpts from them:

"Machine learning is used in physics just as it is used in other field of science or in industry, i.e. when dealing with complex problems and/or lots of data, having computers sharing the hard thinking part"

"Nearly all of what we would call physics consists of fairly simple models, and the urge to construct and understand simple models drives much of what we do. Major exceptions to this: observational astronomy and high energy experiments like the Large Hadron Collider at CERN where machine learning can be effectively applied. Another promising application is in turbulence modeling"

I hope this helps to narrow it down a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but take classes in linear algebra and convex- and nonlinear optimization too.

Answer (score 0):

I agree @Emre. To me, they are all important to machine learning. Of course, it depends **what exactly** you want to do in machine learning. For instance, if you're just doing image recognition you don't need to understand time series.

Another example, "Decision and Game Theory" is absolutely critical for machine learning in board games like chess (e.g reinforcement self-learning).

Everything you list here applies to machine learning - machine learning is really just statistical algorithms for learning an unknown function.

Why don't you tell us what you want to do, and we tell you what you should learn?

I'd give you the top five I think most important in your list (subjective):

- Normal distribution
- Linear Regression
- Random Variables
- Mathematical Expectation
- Binomial Distributions

Comment: thanks @SmallChess. Tried to narrow down the question a bit. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SmallChess, But I have something to add.(since I can't comment yet)

Two concepts would help you to understand most of the Learning Algorithms:

1. Gradient descent
2. Monte Carlo Tree search

These two concepts helped me understanding most other concepts. Hope I helped.